# How to use .loc to set as other column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

For example, I have a dataframe:

```
    cond  value1  value2
0   True       1       1
1  False       3       5
2   True      34       2
3   True      23      23
4  False       4       2
```

I hope to replace value1 to `value2*2` when `cond=True`. So I want the result is:

```
    cond  value1  value2
0   True       2       1
1  False       3       5
2   True       4       2
3   True      46      23
4  False       4       2
```

I can achieve it by follow code:

```
 def convert(x):
     if x.cond:
         x.value1= x.value2*2
     return x
 data = data.apply(lambda x: convert(x),axis=1)
```

I think it is so slow when data is big. I try it by `.loc`, but I don't know how to set value.

How can I achieve it by `.loc` or other simple ways? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create boolean mask and multiple only filtered rows:

```
mask = df.cond
df.loc[mask, 'value1'] =  df.loc[mask, 'value2'] * 2
print (df)
    cond  value1  value2
0   True       2       1
1  False       3       5
2   True       4       2
3   True      46      23
4  False       4       2
```

Comment: I have seen similar questions so many times. Why not create a question like `How to Pivot` and make all possible answers with timeit values. So, that it will good reference for others.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa - yes, this idea should be implemented in huge related function like `pivot`, `pivot_table` and similar, but here not sure what should be in answer - our 4 solutions only? Now I have no idea how is possible expand solutions/ scenarios nice way.

Comment: @jezrael I agree.

Comment: will `df.loc[mask, 'value1'] =  df['value2'] * 2` also work? is applying the same `mask` on the second column necessary?

Comment: @MaxSegal I was surprised to find out that your code works for me. I wonder whether it would still be a better practice to use jezrael's style.

Comment: @OrenMilman - Both solution working well. Difference is if use some complicated operation like [`interpolate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69551169/2901002) for perfromance is better apply it only for filtered rows - e.g. 10 matched rows vs all rows, e.g. 10k rows.

Comment: @OrenMilman - Here is multiple only, it is very fast, so here is performance similar.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `where`/`mask`:

```
df.value1 = df.value1.mask(df.cond, df.value2*2)
# Or,
# df.value1 = df.value1.where(~df.cond, df.value2*2)

print(df)
    cond  value1  value2
0   True       2       1
1  False       3       5
2   True       4       2
3   True      46      23
4  False       4       2
```

Comment: Is pd.mask an attribute of pandas? Thanks I learnt something new!

Comment: It worked well for me, now I am not getting setitem errors.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) :

```
df['value1'] = np.where(df.cond,df.value2*2,df.value1)

print(df)
    cond  value1  value2
0   True       2       1
1  False       3       5
2   True       4       2
3   True      46      23
4  False       4       2
```