# pandas - Assigning loc of dataframe to loc of other dataframe doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use `loc` to selectively copy column values from one dataframe to a slice of another dataframe. However, assigning to the `loc` of the target dataframe leaves it completely unchanged.
This is my code, everything other than the last line is just context, (probably?) unrelated to the problem:

```py
def insert_gps_distance_deviation(df, gps_df, gps_fixed) -> pd.DataFrame:
  first_distance = gps_distance(gps_fixed["lon"], gps_fixed["lat"], gps_df.iloc[0]["lon"], gps_df.iloc[0]["lat"])
  last_distance = gps_distance(gps_fixed["lon"], gps_fixed["lat"], gps_df.iloc[-1]["lon"], gps_df.iloc[-1]["lat"])

  # reconstruct timestamps of GPS data and resample to size of other dataframe
  gps_start_idx = df.iloc[:df.shape[0] // 2,]["distance"].sub(first_distance).abs().idxmin()
  gps_stop_idx = df.iloc[df.shape[0] // 2:,]["distance"].sub(last_distance).abs().idxmin()

  gps_df["timestamp"] = pd.date_range(start=df.loc[gps_start_idx].timestamp, end=df.loc[gps_stop_idx].timestamp, periods=gps_df.shape[0])
  gps_df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
  
  gps_slice = df.loc[gps_start_idx:gps_stop_idx]
  gps_df = gps_df.resample("%sns" % (floor((gps_slice["timestamp"] - gps_slice["timestamp"].shift(1)).mean().value))).interpolate()

  df["lat"] = np.nan
  df["lon"] = np.nan
  df.loc[gps_start_idx:gps_stop_idx, ["lat", "lon"]] = gps_df.loc[:, ["lat", "lon"]]
```

`gps_start_idx` and `gps_stop_idx` are indices returned from [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html), so I should be able to use them inside `loc`. I also don't see anything in the [`loc` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) that would suggest what I'm trying to do is invalid. It doesn't say anything about assigning another `loc`, but I have found code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53221079/14410015) doing exactly that, so I thought it would work. I also get no error messages or warnings about setting values on a dataframe copy or anything like that when running the code.

What am I doing wrong here?
If what I am trying to do using `loc` is not possible, what is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `df.iloc[0]` you get a Series, but if you call `df.iloc[df.idxmin()]` (where `df.idxmin() = 0`) you get a Dataframe.

So do `gps_start_idx = int(gps_start_idx)` and `gps_stop_idx = int(gps_stop_idx)` and then run it through the `df.loc[]`.

(putting this as an answer instead of comment since it did work for me in my test so should actually work for you.)

(It also isn't super clear to me *why* one being a series or a dataframe matters all that match, but it is different, and it works, so /shrug/)

Comment: Hmm that didn't do anything. I think the problem is not really related to `gps_start_idx` and `gps_stop_idx`, but more to trying to assign one `loc` to another. Especially the rhs of the assignment. I changed the code to `df.loc[gps_start_idx:gps_stop_idx, ["lat", "lon"]] = 10` as a test, and it worked as expected.